# webstageview not loading on phone but working in emulator

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm trying to get a webstageview to load a local html file....this code works perfectly on the emulator, but when i run it on my android device (running android 2.3), it does not work....it just creates a blank webstageview that never loads the local html file...the zoom function is intact so i know it's opening the webstageview, but i never see the content....any advice? i am stuck...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:ns1="*"
    xmlns:controls="com.flexcapacitor.controls.*"
    actionBarVisible="false" backKeyPressed="onBackKeyPressed(event)"
    creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" title="{data.image}"
    xmlns:components="com.flexcapacitor.components.*">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.components.ViewNavigator;

        public var webView1:StageWebView=new StageWebView();


        protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {

            webView1.stage=this.stage;
            webView1.viewPort=new Rectangle(0,50,stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
            var fPath:String=new File(new File("app:/"+data.html).nativePath).url;
            webView1.loadURL(fPath);


        }
        protected function onBackKeyPressed(event:FlexEvent):void{
            webView1.viewPort = null;
            webView1.dispose();
            webView1 = null;
        }


        protected function backbutton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            webView1.viewPort = null;
            webView1.dispose();
            webView1 = null;
            navigator.popView();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Button id="backbackbutton" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="50" label="Back" click="backbutton_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ended up having to make some temporary files to open it properly....not sure why it wouldn't work before even though the emulator worked fine...here's the code that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:ns1="*"
    xmlns:controls="com.flexcapacitor.controls.*"
    actionBarVisible="false" backKeyPressed="onBackKeyPressed(event)"
    creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" title="{data.image}"
    xmlns:components="com.flexcapacitor.components.*">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.components.ViewNavigator;

        public var webView1:StageWebView=new StageWebView();


        protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {

            webView1.stage=this.stage;
            webView1.viewPort=new Rectangle(0,50,stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
          var fa:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(data.html);
            var f2a:File = File.createTempDirectory();
            var fb:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(data.location);
            fa.copyTo(f2a.resolvePath(data.html),true);
            fb.copyTo(f2a.resolvePath(data.location),true);
            webView1.loadURL(f2a.url + File.separator +data.html);


        }
        protected function onBackKeyPressed(event:FlexEvent):void{
            webView1.viewPort = null;
            webView1.dispose();
            webView1 = null;
        }


        protected function backbutton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            webView1.viewPort = null;
            webView1.dispose();
            webView1 = null;
            navigator.popView();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Button id="backbackbutton" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="50" label="Back"
          accentColor="#000000" chromeColor="#404040" click="backbutton_clickHandler(event)"
          color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Comment: emulator = AIR's inbuilt emulator or Google's Android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your 'app' folder to your build path so the html file is included in your release build?  If not, right click on your project and go to properties > Actionscript Build Path > Source Path > Add Folder...

Comment: everything is under my original src folder. The full path is src/assets/chapter1images/image1.html      .    data.html = "assets/chapter1images/image1.html     i tried adding in a line that says trace("attempting to load "+fPath);    and the trace reads out the following    attempting to load file:///C:/Users/Brett/Adobe%20Flash%20Builder%204.5/graysanatomymobile3/bin-debug/assets/chapter1images/image1.html                   why would this run in the emulator but not on the device?       do i still need to add a folder to my source path if it's a sub-folder of src??

Comment: My best guess is that you don't have access to the Android file system when running on the device, or fPath is unintelligible when running on the device.

Comment: Have you tried webView1.loadURL('assets/chapter1images/image1.html') ?